# Area under a curve between limits unbounded on one end and x=a

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
   \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

   \usetikzlibrary{patterns} % for "schraffierte" lines
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
   \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
   \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
    title={Neyman Pearson Alpha Representation},
    grid=major,
    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
    xlabel={x values},
    ylabel={y values},
    %xmin=0, xmax=20,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.1,
    %ymode=log,
    %ymin=0, ymax=1.35,
    %xtick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300},
    %ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
    legend pos=north west,
    enlarge y limits={abs=1cm,upper}
    %ymajorgrids=true,
    %grid style=dashed,
    %xmajorgrids=true
    %grid style=dashed
]
\addplot[
    name path=U,
    color=blue,]
    coordinates {(-44.848214732850224, 6.894645067806492e-07)
    (-44.57635519136731, 1.5335076456603906e-06)
    (-44.30449564988441, 3.179761069727552e-06)
    (-44.0326361084015, 6.148889876285282e-06)
    (-43.760776566918594, 1.10937371897585e-05)
    (-43.48891702543568, 1.8683210673628567e-05)
    (-43.21705748395278, 2.9387382547012065e-05)
    (-42.94519794246987, 4.319955281138747e-05)
    (-42.673338400986964, 5.938929762902865e-05)
    (-42.40147885950405, 7.6414292131392e-05)
    (-42.12961931802115, 9.209294148968027e-05)
    (-41.85775977653824, 0.00010404711057331556)
    (-41.585900235055334, 0.00011030078629595235)
    (-41.31404069357242, 0.000109832023101698)
    (-41.04218115208951, 0.00010287647076595105)
    (-40.77032161060661, 9.087623596113042e-05)
    (-40.4984620691237, 7.610817275377553e-05)
    (-40.22660252764079, 6.1139158343419e-05)
    (-39.95474298615788, 4.829391104205787e-05)
    (-39.68288344467498, 3.9283191743289394e-05)
    (-39.41102390319207, 3.506482999018231e-05)
    (-39.13916436170916, 3.593973512414593e-05)
    (-38.86730482022625, 4.1837267341224136e-05)
    (-38.59544527874335, 5.270683195305673e-05)
    (-38.32358573726044, 6.888846794696949e-05)
    (-38.05172619577753, 9.129590100201937e-05)
    (-37.77986665429462, 0.00012125802380135891)
    (-37.50800711281171, 0.00015997575355931602)
    (-37.23614757132881, 0.00020774924641827892)
    (-36.964288029845896, 0.0002633194172860166)
    (-36.69242848836299, 0.0003237125694420689)
    (-36.42056894688008, 0.00038480332949224596)
    (-36.14870940539718, 0.00044248219468474024)
    (-35.876849863914266, 0.0004940100416894872)
    (-35.60499032243136, 0.0005390422705063198)
    (-35.33313078094845, 0.0005799601905271269)
    (-35.06127123946554, 0.0006214447783767588)
    (-34.789411697982636, 0.000669484983196033)
    (-34.51755215649973, 0.0007301148849723863)
    (-34.24569261501682, 0.0008081455980307046)
    (-33.97383307353391, 0.0009061070438093106)
    (-33.70197353205101, 0.0010236101457950836)
    (-33.430113990568096, 0.0011573380751522366)
    (-33.15825444908519, 0.001301771800645149)
    (-32.88639490760228, 0.0014505148345369924)
    (-32.61453536611938, 0.0015978141053263684)
    (-32.342675824636466, 0.0017397661732941152)
    (-32.07081628315356, 0.0018748563292110927)
    (-31.79895674167065, 0.0020038228887075613)
    (-31.527097200187743, 0.002129161236098114)
    (-31.255237658704836, 0.0022547023562183616)
    (-30.98337811722193, 0.0023855774178484293)
    (-30.71151857573902, 0.0025285899766276363)
    (-30.439659034256113, 0.0026926765921573524)
    (-30.167799492773206, 0.00288887445804216)
    (-29.895939951290295, 0.003129194197836001)
    (-29.62408040980739, 0.003424169947660831)
    (-29.35222086832448, 0.0037796132328049093)
    (-29.080361326841576, 0.00419391247774378)
    (-28.808501785358665, 0.004657547392463743)
    (-28.536642243875757, 0.005155882892785484)
    (-28.26478270239285, 0.0056748192834542455)
    (-27.992923160909942, 0.006207176081131369)
    (-27.721063619427035, 0.006756775612226696)
    (-27.449204077944128, 0.007337799203189873)
    (-27.17734453646122, 0.007969040513738574)
    (-26.905484994978313, 0.00866521532100629)
    (-26.633625453495405, 0.009429141241895941)
    (-26.361765912012498, 0.010248409255211706)
    (-26.08990637052959, 0.011098165291282299)
    (-25.818046829046683, 0.011948834174854277)
    (-25.54618728756377, 0.012775473432696447)
    (-25.274327746080864, 0.013564961502489842)
    (-25.002468204597957, 0.014318515537620006)
    (-24.73060866311505, 0.01504932688106691)
    (-24.45874912163214, 0.01577720533513981)
    (-24.186889580149234, 0.016523040202726998)
    (-23.915030038666327, 0.017305294223862868)
    (-23.64317049718342, 0.018139130197882335)
    (-23.371310955700512, 0.01903713368814644)
    (-23.099451414217604, 0.020009880093378396)
    (-22.827591872734697, 0.021065122382592012)
    (-22.55573233125179, 0.022205680276165596)
    (-22.283872789768882, 0.023427282626250205)
    (-22.01201324828597, 0.024717916958975725)
    (-21.740153706803063, 0.026059563521907726)
    (-21.468294165320156, 0.027432039346067815)
    (-21.19643462383725, 0.028817759609924547)
    (-20.92457508235434, 0.030205979006977562)
    (-20.652715540871434, 0.031595456311677615)
    (-20.380855999388526, 0.03299508621844504)
    (-20.10899645790562, 0.03442244945498294)
    (-19.83713691642271, 0.035900330037910655)
    (-19.565277374939804, 0.03745128013792869)
    (-19.293417833456896, 0.039090641736528306)
    (-19.02155829197399, 0.040819184343076124)
    (-18.749698750491078, 0.04261738316454194)
    (-18.47783920900817, 0.04444375273099176)
    (-18.205979667525263, 0.0462390700417067)
    (-17.934120126042355, 0.04793669038575741)
    (-17.662260584559448, 0.04947692033720996)
    (-17.39040104307654, 0.050821426341573765)
    (-17.118541501593633, 0.05196293488080258)
    (-16.846681960110725, 0.05292671075011648)
    (-16.574822418627818, 0.05376327258266576)
    (-16.30296287714491, 0.054535177157891974)
    (-16.031103335662003, 0.05530261359505334)
    (-15.759243794179095, 0.05611190883346318)
    (-15.487384252696188, 0.05698852332171388)
    (-15.215524711213277, 0.05793375508292683)
    (-14.94366516973037, 0.05892395066356531)
    (-14.671805628247462, 0.05991250342435047)
    (-14.399946086764555, 0.060836424770028444)
    (-14.128086545281647, 0.06162872194262811)
    (-13.85622700379874, 0.0622348344112881)
    (-13.584367462315832, 0.06262782880200887)
    (-13.312507920832925, 0.0628156850968826)
    (-13.040648379350017, 0.06283635869855936)
    (-12.768788837867106, 0.0627414657077605)
    (-12.496929296384202, 0.06257464701471209)
    (-12.225069754901291, 0.06235316087418032)
    (-11.953210213418387, 0.06205995644183585)
    (-11.681350671935476, 0.06164932159687028)
    (-11.409491130452572, 0.06106413732294054)
    (-11.137631588969661, 0.06025859825559626)
    (-10.865772047486757, 0.059218125758380154)
    (-10.593912506003846, 0.05796879474188302)
    (-10.322052964520942, 0.05657214215003382)
    (-10.050193423038031, 0.055106922897218656)
    (-9.77833388155512, 0.053644999900476185)
    (-9.506474340072216, 0.052231205097004206)
    (-9.234614798589305, 0.05087497071166143)
    (-8.962755257106402, 0.0495557356631435)
    (-8.69089571562349, 0.048237801582604)
    (-8.419036174140587, 0.04688685367184368)
    (-8.147176632657676, 0.04548117883831581)
    (-7.875317091174772, 0.044014514450935294)
    (-7.603457549691861, 0.04249186470277042)
    (-7.331598008208957, 0.04092235254788325)
    (-7.059738466726046, 0.0393134742027195)
    (-6.787878925243142, 0.03766949318539168)
    (-6.516019383760231, 0.035994197833888936)
    (-6.24415984227732, 0.03429589578668497)
    (-5.972300300794416, 0.03259120527860428)
    (-5.700440759311505, 0.030904533927404994)
    (-5.428581217828601, 0.029262175547531293)
    (-5.15672167634569, 0.027682928162831397)
    (-4.884862134862786, 0.026169535488865126)
    (-4.613002593379875, 0.02470557578011672)
    (-4.341143051896971, 0.023260172086468446)
    (-4.06928351041406, 0.021799127615922266)
    (-3.797423968931156, 0.02029790220358859)
    (-3.525564427448245, 0.018751069902600576)
    (-3.253704885965341, 0.017174857059627163)
    (-2.98184534448243, 0.015602698679161907)
    (-2.709985802999519, 0.014076468612177265)
    (-2.438126261516615, 0.01263689697357968)
    (-2.166266720033704, 0.01131586176838851)
    (-1.8944071785508, 0.010131818660062642)
    (-1.622547637067889, 0.009088561672300974)
    (-1.3506880955849851, 0.008176971035822633)
    (-1.0788285541020741, 0.007379039853001706)
    (-0.8069690126191702, 0.0066730224962892335)
    (-0.5351094711362592, 0.006038217049122166)
    (-0.26324992965335525, 0.0054580872739756385)
    (0.008609611829555774, 0.004921235581618104)
    (0.2804691533124597, 0.004420724404616035)
    (0.5523286947953707, 0.003952784447570136)
    (0.8241882362782817, 0.003515762593755623)
    (1.0960477777611857, 0.0031095297634107662)
    (1.3679073192440967, 0.002735047682159299)
    (1.6397668607270006, 0.002393735207100456)
    (1.9116264022099116, 0.002086592905844755)
    (2.1834859436928156, 0.0018133856968128588)
    (2.4553454851757266, 0.0015722674285204863)
    (2.7272050266586305, 0.0013600351293569237)
    (2.9990645681415415, 0.0011728913294078399)
    (3.2709241096244455, 0.001007358143673619)
    (3.5427836511073565, 0.0008609314361960009)
    (3.8146431925902604, 0.0007321993069101023)
    (4.086502734073171, 0.0006204143192520276)
    (4.3583622755560825, 0.0005247814086312176)
    (4.630221817038986, 0.0004438605817209732)
    .............)

   };
\addplot[
    name path=S,
    color=red,]
    coordinates {(-8.983669518808362, 8.168426471830885e-07)
    (-8.801753562288608, 1.859536502224723e-06)
    (-8.619837605768852, 3.94044940676042e-06)
    (-8.437921649249098, 7.77921398354473e-06)
    (-8.256005692729344, 1.4322432791774316e-05)
    (-8.074089736209588, 2.4621298715551884e-05)
    (-7.892173779689834, 3.957606800243734e-05)
    (-7.71025782317008, 5.958016287984825e-05)
    (-7.528341866650325, 8.416967243238451e-05)
    (-7.34642591013057, 0.00011183065594377776)
    (-7.164509953610816, 0.00014009532938004163)
    (-6.982593997091061, 0.00016596140950969377)
    (-6.800678040571306, 0.00018653909685872476)
    (-6.618762084051552, 0.000199736813928316)
    (-6.436846127531797, 0.00020478663126920958)
    (-6.254930171012042, 0.00020247360309094385)
    (-6.073014214492288, 0.00019501915460398594)
    (-5.8910982579725335, 0.00018563658507737645)
    (-5.7091823014527785, 0.0001778312092408758)
    (-5.5272663449330235, 0.00017458772696581182)
    (-5.345350388413269, 0.00017767067266827793)
    (-5.163434431893514, 0.00018730015446731966)
    (-4.981518475373759, 0.00020238161471916374)
    (-4.799602518854005, 0.00022125966731574562)
    (-4.61768656233425, 0.0002427268092853403)
    (-4.435770605814495, 0.00026688409995188667)
    (-4.253854649294741, 0.0002955005352321601)
    (-4.071938692774986, 0.00033172055096266343)
    (-3.890022736255231, 0.00037922296819117705)
    (-3.708106779735477, 0.0004411384574387679)
    (-3.526190823215722, 0.0005191251230454707)
    (-3.344274866695968, 0.0006129577659436089)
    (-3.162358910176213, 0.0007208072751246381)
    (-2.980442953656458, 0.0008401136873167292)
    (-2.7985269971367037, 0.0009686874041650691)
    (-2.6166110406169487, 0.0011055450198407296)
    (-2.4346950840971946, 0.0012511081455186875)
    .......};

\addplot [name path=line] coordinates {(1.63621746301651,0)(1.63621746301651,0.15)};
\addplot[name path=alpha,red!100] fill between[of= U and line ,soft clip={domain=1.63621746301651 :\infty}];
\addplot[name path=alpha,red!100] fill between[of= S and line ,soft clip={domain=1.63621746301651 : -\infty}];    
\legend{U,S}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am looking to shade the region under the red curve, lesser than the threshold line indicated by black vertical line in latex.

I defined coordinates for U inside \addplot.

In order to shade the red region (U> threshold), I used the following line of code

```
\addplot[name path=alpha,red!100] fill between[of= U and line ,soft clip {domain=1.63621746301651 :\infty}];
```

But when I try to shade the region under S curve lesser than the threshold line using the following code

```
\addplot[name path=alpha,red!100] fill between[of= S and line ,soft clip {domain=1.63621746301651 : -\infty}];
```

It does not work. It shades the region under S greater than threshold (refer to error image[image: error]). How can this be rectified?

Expected result- [image: expectedresult]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be tremendously helpful, if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). It does not need to contain the real values, just something that shows what you did so far and which problem you got.

Comment: Edited above to include the minimum working example. But there are a lot more coordinates for each curve. Basically I am looking for the region less than the threshold line under the red curve S. But what is shaded is the compliment of it

Comment: I am not sure that you can use `\infty` as value for `domain`. Try using a large value, such as `100` instead.

Comment: It did work for +infinity in the first case where the limits were between threshold line and +infinity under curve U. But for second case where the limits are -infinity and threshold, it doesnt work

Comment: Added an image of expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fillbetween`, filling vertically often works much better than filling horizontally. That is, you should probably not use the vertical plot which you named `line` as one of the plots to fill an area, but instead add another plot that represents *y* = 0 and name this plot `line`. This way, you can easily fill the area beneath each of the other two plots. You can then use the `domain` option to restrict this area up to *x* = 1.63621746301651 (or whatever value you want to choose).

I shortened you code a bit and simplified the coordinate lists for the curves.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Neyman Pearson Alpha Representation},
    grid=major,
    grid style={dashed, gray!30},
    xlabel={x values},
    ylabel={y values},
    ymin=0, ymax=0.1,
    legend pos=north west,
    enlarge y limits={abs=1cm, upper}
]
\addplot[
    name path=U,
    color=blue,
    smooth
] coordinates {
    (-44.848214732850224, 6.894645067806492e-07)
    (-37.50800711281171, 0.00015997575355931602)
    (-20.380855999388526, 0.03299508621844504)
    (-13.312507920832925, 0.0628156850968826)
    (-6.380855999388526, 0.03299508621844504)
    (11.50800711281171, 0.00015997575355931602)
    (26.848214732850224, 6.894645067806492e-07)
};
\addplot[
    name path=S,
    color=red,
    smooth
] coordinates {
    (-8.983669518808362, 8.168426471830885e-07)
    (-2.4346950840971946, 0.0012511081455186875)
    (0.4346950840971946, 0.012511081455186875)
    (6.4346950840971946, 0.10511081455186875)
    (12.4346950840971946, 0.012511081455186875)
    (14.4346950840971946, 0.0012511081455186875)
    (20.983669518808362, 8.168426471830885e-07)
};

\addplot[no markers] coordinates {(1.63621746301651,0) (1.63621746301651,0.15)};

\addplot[name path=line, draw=none] {0};

\addplot[name path=alpha, red!20] 
    fill between[of=U and line, soft clip={domain=1.63621746301651 : 100}];

\addplot[name path=alpha, blue!20] 
    fill between[of=S and line, soft clip={domain=1.63621746301651 : -100}];    
    
\legend{U,S}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :)